# Copi and Four Rules of Logical Identity

Tags: logic, proof-verification

See : Irving Copi, [Symbolic Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=rEjuAAAAMAAJ) (4th ed, 1973), page 138: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG0bJ.jpg).

The reflexive identity rule is:

> $\dfrac { \text p} {x=x}$ (*reflexivity*);

Does this mean that if I have $Fc$, I can then infer $c = c$ in my proof?

I got $Fc$ after applying universal out to $(x)[Fx \text { & } Sx]$. What does the $\text p$ actual stand for?

Thank you!

Comment: Presumably it is $\dfrac {Prem}{x=x}$ and states that in a derivation you can insert the formula $x=x$ after any line (after any premise).

Comment: You're right, I should have added more information but I could not find an online version of Irvine Copi's logic book. I added a picture of the relevant page that I am concerned with. I have read the entire chapter but am still a bit confused. It is the section where he talks about the Identity Rules and Russell's Theory of Descriptions. I did not get Fc from the premises but I got that from when I did universal out on (Fx & Sx).

Answer (score 1):

Typically this rule is stated as:

$$\frac{}{t=t}$$

... which makes it a lot more clear that you don't need anything in order to conclude or infer $t =t$ for any term $t$ .... because that is always true of course!

So maybe the $P$ expresses the idea that you can have infer $t=t$ from $anything$, it doesn't matter what.  Even as such, it still seems a little restrictive to say that I would need *something* at all (what if I have no premises to start out in the first place?) ... so I doubt that that is what they really meant anyway. So in the end I feel it is a rather poor way of expressing that you can infer $t=t$ at any point in the proof, without reference to any earlier statement.

Answer (score 0):

The $\text p$ in the rule presumably stands for : $\text {premise}$

It means that in a derivation you can insert the formula $x=x$ after any line (after any premise).

The rule reflects (see page 137) the *reflexivity* of the identity relation :

> $(x)(x=x)$.

---

> Does this mean that if I have $Fc$, I can then infer $c = c$ in my proof ?

Yes : you can infer $c=c$ wherever you want in the proof, and thus also after $Fc$.